# In Ruby on Rails, cannot render :controller => 'generic', :action => 'top_pages' but need to use :template => 'generic/top_pages'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rendering, action

it seems that the `:controller` option doesn't do anything?  Won't specifying the whole path be a little bit lower level than specifying using `:controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, i checked the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), there is no `:controller` option, and i think it is just ignored.

Also, i believe it is a shorter notation. If you compare

```
:template => 'controller/action'
```

with

```
:controller => 'controller', :action => 'action'
```

It is pretty obvious (at least to me) that it has the same meaning. 
Also, this is more generic, because sometimes controllers (and views) are nested.